# How to copy multiple file from one s3 to another s3 based on the given prefix?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have multiple files in the s3 bucket which I am trying to move to a different bucket that matches the given prefixes.

```
File Names: test001, test002, test003, test004, example1, example2
```

I am using AWS cp command in the Bash Script to move files but it's not working for me.

```
aws s3 cp s3://example-1//test s3://example-2/test --recursive
```

Can you please tell me how can I move files from one bucket to another which matches the prefix?

Answer (score 1):

Run this command (with your actual s3 source and destination endpoints) to copy the files with names that begin with `"test"` and "example":

```
aws s3 cp s3://srcbucket/ s3://destbucket/ --recursive --exclude "*" --include "test*" --include "example*"
```

The `--exclude` and `--include` parameters are processed on the client side. Because of this, the resources of your local machine might affect the performance of the operation.

Comment: I did try this but the problem I was getting into is that I was trying to get files that have "test1" or "Test2" but it's getting all the files where I have "test" in that name. How can I make it only for the files where filename is "test1" or "test2"?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
aws s3 cp s3://example-1/ s3://example-2/ --include "test*" --recursive
```